# Passing Objective-C objects from NSArray to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have a `NSArray` containing objects. I want to create a secondary `NSArray` containing just some of the objects in the first `NSArray`. I have something like:

```objc
[array1 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (something) {
        [array2 addObject:obj]; // (1)
    }
}];
[array1 release]; // (2)
```

I'm thinking that `(1)` will increase the object's `retainCount` (which will bring it from 1 to 2), then `(2)` will decrease it (which will bring it from 2 to 1 for the objects added in `array2` and from 1 to 0 for the objects that did not get added).

So I expect that, after doing this, it will be safe to access the objects from `array2`, and the non-conformant objects that did not pass the test will be deallocated.

Is this correct?

Comment: Not sure if just a typo but you will need an `NSMutableArray` for the second array

Comment: This, I fear, is a less-than-desirable strategy. You really should be filtering `array1` against a predicate. See [`+[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) and [`-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html). An added benefit of this clearer approach is that you don't have to think so hard about memory management! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the non-conformant objects are not being retained elsewhere, your assumption is  correct with the following caveats:

1. Note that `retainCount` is generally considered a tricky measure and it's better to talk about the problem is terms of whether `array1` is retaining the non-conformant objects or not, without reference to `retainCount`. The reason is that the `retainCount` may be (and often is) different from what you expect.
2. Also note that array2 must be a `NSMutableArray` instance, otherwise you cannot call `addObject:`.
3. In 95% of cases (made up statistic), you should not use `retain` and `release` yourself, but should prefer using `autorelease` (if the object is NARCed, new alloc retained or copied) or nothing at all if the object is already autoreleased (e.g., `[NSMutableArray array]`).

Comment: Sending a message to a dellocated object is undefined behavior. It might blow your program up, or it might make it look like the object is still alive with a valid retain count even though it isn't, or it might send dirty email to your boss. (The former two are more likely, though.)